# Inventory Transactions between locations - Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, inventory-management

I'm currently working on an Inventory Control db that allows tracking stock transactions from one location to another but, I can't figure out how to create 2 records simultaneously on a "Transactions" Table based on the same data.

Basically, I'd like to create a form where I enter Item, Qty, From Location, To Location, Lot and have 2 records created simultaneously with a negative qty on the "From Location Record" and a Positive Qty on the "To Location Record".

I've attached a screenshot of the Form I envision and the desired Output in Data Records.

I have some experience working with Access forms and tables but this development is beyond my knowledge.

I Hope someone can help.

**Thanks!**

[Form & Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJb0P.png)

Comment: That's what _transactions_ are for. Study this fundamental concept carefully before you move on.

Answer (score 0):

You would run couple of simple insert queries. One to move the stock out from the existing location, one to add it back to the new location.

If you are not well versed with writing VBA I would use the query designer, and include your form text boxes as the criteria. Save the queries, then use your button to run the queries one after the other.

I would also be tempted to bring in the existing location as a combo box based on the part number selected. That way you won't try and move something from a location that isn't correct,

Comment: Hi Minty, I've tried your suggestion but the Append Query is not inserting the records. 

After running it I get a "You are about to append 0 rows(s)" message

Does the form needs to be linked to the table where I want to insert the records?

Form name is called "Stock Move"

Table name is "Transactions"

Text box on the form as well as the field on the "Transactions" table where I want to insert data are called "Item"


The Append Query looks like:

Field: Item
Table: Transactions
Sort:
Append To:
Criteria: [Forms]![Stock Move]![Item]

Any idea of what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you post up the actual SQL of your query?

Comment: Hi Minty, I've managed to make the Append Queries work! Thank you very much for your help!